# Why doesn't the render focal length match my camera focal length?

Tags: rendering, camera

[image: adjusted camera focal length]
[image: render is stuck at 50mm]

I've changed the focal length of my camera from ~50mm to 35mm
I want to be able to see the door and the ceiling in the rendering
BUT the rendering is stuck on 50mm
As you can see in Image 2, the ceiling and door are cut off.
I've tried:
-re-saving and re-starting Blender
-making a new camera altogether and setting it as the active camera

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure that you've selected the good camera in the Scene panel? Please share your file so that we can check: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Thanks for answering! 
Yes I did check :)

Comment: Woops, meant to add: Something weird is that the focal length doesn't always save... Like I change it to 35mm then close Blender and re-open and it's at 50mm again. Here's the file: https://pasteall.org/blend/726cdf2243f64fb8a6bfc3935f82c75e

Comment: weird because it works fine for me, the camera view matches with the render: https://zupimages.net/up/22/20/nsg6.jpg

Comment: Thanks for checking it moonboots! So the camera view / render view in your screenshots is ~50mm, not 35mm. As I mentioned, changing the camera focal length to 35mm doesn't seem to stick when I save and close. Do you mind checking if you're able to change the camera lens length to 35mm and see if it's still set that way when you close and re-open blender? Maybe that's part of why I can't render the 35mm view?

Comment: it still works, but note that you've keyframed your Focal Length, so if you change its value, make sure that you keyframe again with the new value, or remove this keyframe, otherwise it will go back to the keyframed value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've keyframed the *Focal Length* of your camera at 50, so if you ever want to change the focal length you need to either remove the existing keyframe or keyframe the new value, otherwise the render will stay at a focal length of 50:

[image]

Comment: Oh my gosh, that was it! Thanks so much for figuring it out!! Much appreciated!!!